# Handset is not recognised by eclipse "offline"?

Tags: android, smartphone

I have connected my device with the computer, and i was testing my APPs. and everything was working just fine. Unexpectedly, i found my device is not recognised by eclipse and it's offline as in the attached image below.

Any Suggestions, and sorry if my post is not in the appropriate section.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue with my device several times.
Unplug the device. You should be able to fix this simply by restarting the adb server.
or, kill the adb server and restart the eclipse.

```
c:>adb kill-server
```

Restarting the eclipse will start the adb server.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug the device and replug it.  ADB will refind the device and it should work.

Comment: You may have to reboot your phone, I had to yesterday when eclipse bugged on me in a similar fashion and replugging didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Update your sdk manager.
Window> Android sdk manger..
And update