# Just upgraded my OS X to Yosemite, Android Device Chooser not showing device - what to do?

Tags: android, eclipse, device, detection

After upgrading to OS X Yosemite I found that eclipse was not working because JAVA was not properly installed. I installed it and now I am able to open eclipse.

When I connect my device, I am able to see my device on the device list in eclipse. However when I run my project, I am unable to see it on Android device chooser. My device is getting detected by Eclipse but I am not able to select it to run.

This was working perfectly on my previous OS X Mavericks! Please help!

Thanks

Comment: I just updated to the latest ADT/tools (23.0.6.1720515) *and* to the latest Eclipse (Luna Service Release 2 4.4.2) and I no longer have this bug!

Comment: Relevant issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78436

Answer (score 203, accepted):

It seems to be a layout bug.

Drag one of the column headers in the device chooser where the device should be and change the column width and it magically appears!

[image: Workaround for bug in Android Device Chooser]

You can also double click the device's row even when it's hidden, so you don't have to resize the column each time.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me a lot of time too. I was connecting and disconnecting devices to get them on the screen.

Comment: OMFG!!! I just spent 3 hours messing around with my settings, uninstalling, and reinstalling stuff, thinking it was an issue with my setup or my device. Thanks Google for your quality control! It seems like every time I open an Android project that I haven't worked on for a few weeks I have to spend at least an hour getting Eclipse back into working order. Matt, thanks for the great find! +1

Comment: this work with me for the emulators , but real devices still have problem !

Comment: Very very strange bug this is happening on OS 10.10. Was working fine OS 10.9 Thanks for sharing and saving my time :)

Comment: Double clicking on the invisible row would still perform the action!

Comment: Perhaps Google did this on purpose?! You never know ;-) Thanks for a great find, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Does anyone know if this was filed as a bug with Google?

Comment: Thank You! I had noticed that unplugging and replugging the device also makes it pop up so I thought that it was a hardware issue.

Answer (score 4):

Another working solution is:

**Disconnect and reconnect the device while the Android Device Chooser Popup is open.**

Comment: Both solutions are ok, when you have already run the application once, this is this one that works, not the layout problem

Comment: it was working for me only one case when i connected my real device it shows running emulators in Android Device Chooser. but Matt's awnser working for me.

Comment: and destroy your USB port

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one device connected, tap the down arrow on your keyboard to reveal the hidden device. Then click OK or press Enter like normal. Otherwise, just press Enter. The device is already there, just not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem, after upgrading to Yosemite, but with a BlackBerry 10 device running an Android build from Eclipse.

Solution:
Run app and wait for the Android Device Chooser to popup.  My dialog showed an empty list.
Whilst the dialog is showing, disconnect and reconnect the device via the BlackBerry adb proxy.  After doing so, the BlackBerry device automatically showed up in the dialog and I could choose it and run the build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was ticking on/off the USB debugging mode in the device Developers options, but the solution in the selected answer is better...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a Eclipse UI view refresh issue new to Yosemite.  I notice that my logcat filter textview goes completely white as soon as it loses focus - making it look like you have no filter defined. Gross.