# Can't find running Android device in ADT after Mac upgrade to 10.10 (yosemite)

Tags: android, macos

I have upgrade my mac system to Yosemite(10.10) yesterday,and after that my Eclipse (ADT) can not find the running andriod device for debug. I have reinstall the jdk6 just as suggestion after upgrade.

Any solution?

Comment: I have the same issue when trying to debug on a real device. The ADT does not detect a device even though the device is shown in DDMS.

Comment: The question seems to be duplicate, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416532/just-upgraded-my-os-x-to-yosemite-android-device-chooser-not-showing-device-w

Comment: I found this solution to the problem from another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416532/just-upgraded-my-os-x-to-yosemite-android-device-chooser-not-showing-device-w