# adb (android debug bridge) problems after OSX Yosemite upgrade

Tags: android, adb, osx-yosemite

I've upgraded my 2011 13inch Macbook yesterday to yosemite.

Now i am experiencing problems with the adb tool (1.0.31, 1.0.32) e.g. when installing a build on the device, copying a file via ddms. From eclipse, android studio and the command line the same performance, around 80 kb/s. 85 KB/s (68736634 bytes in 788.742s)

Tested with a samsung and an htc device, no big differences.

Copying files to the devices with the Android File Transfer App behaves normally!

Anyone here where this is working properly or anyone experiencing the same? Thinking about downgrading to Mavericks.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: With a clean new install of yosemite I don't have this problem. After migrating my Time Machine backup it appears again, even deleting all sdks, eclipse, android studio did not solve it so far.

Comment: I'm having the same problem since upgrading to Yosemite: I have to unplug and plug in the device every time I want to use it.

Comment: @Andrew Wyld This I have too, but it seems to be more like a layout problem, if you rescale the grid in the device chooser dialog the devices magically appear

Comment: check this solution, it's work with me 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26425489/2225038

Comment: Amazingly, if you just drag the device chooser grid it does just appear as @user96881 says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue on my 2012 Macbook after updating to Yosemite. It turned out the problem was caused by an old version of VMWave Fusion, but unfortunately just deleting it didn't help. I did a clean install (deleting the drive first) of Yosemite, and installed all apps (apart form VMWare) manually - restoring time machine wasn't helping.

If you have VMWare/VirtualBox or similar, maybe you can try removing those.

Comment: I had this exact same problem and got it working by uninstalling VMWare Fusion using App Cleaner (http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner). It found a bunch of extra files VMWare Fusion was using as well as the app itself. After using it to uninstall, and rebooting my machine, adb works fine again.

Comment: hm, I have virtualbox, which I use for my android emulator Genymotion. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the adbkey and adbkey.pub files fixed this for me. You may have to restart the adb server to regenerate the keys (in my case android studio did this for me).

Comment: I had a different issue than the OP, like the phone was always asking to accept the adb requests. Plus other issues I suppose. I just discovered thanks to your post that my ~/.android folder was owned by root..