# adb devices not recognizing device in Yosemite

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x, adb, android-virtual-device

I have 2 partition Maverick and Yosemite. In the Maverick partition in the documents I have the sdk and ndk folder. I have installed Eclipse Juno seperately installed on both the OS.

On the Maverick the projects build perfectly on both the AVD and the Device when it is plugged in.

On Yosemite the projects build on the AVD but the Device is just not detected. I have linked the SDK folder in the Maverick partition to the Eclipse in Yosemite. On the maverick as soon as I connect the device the ANdroid-File-Transfer app opens automatically, in Yosemite it doesnt. And on the Yosemite if I go to the platformtools folder and type ./adb devices nothing shows, but if I do the same on the maverick it shows the Nexus 5 connected.

On the Yosemite when I connect the device the device and system recognize that Nexus 5 is connected as I can in the system report.

In an another question it says to restart the server or expand the avd column, I tried both but still device doesnt show...

Comment: Try a different USB port, make sure its not connected on a hub or keyboard but directly on a builtin USB port. Try unplugging & replugging as well as restarting Eclipse in between.

Comment: I do use an extension cable, but the same setup works on Maverick... so I dont see why it shouldnt work on Yosemite... I will give it a shot and let you know tho...

Comment: possible duplicate of [adb (android debug bridge) problems after OSX Yosemite upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495199/adb-android-debug-bridge-problems-after-osx-yosemite-upgrade)

Comment: I am not using a virtual machine and I am not using a bridge.... so it is not the same problem.. I think

Comment: Others are also having same problem... http://www.techonce.net/threads/272775-Android-adb-won-t-find-my-android-device-on-Yosemite