# Eclipse Android Plug in Device detection

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have the following problem: 
I'm using Eclipse with the Android ADT Plugin on a Mac.
When connecting my phone (Vodafone 975N, Jelly Bean) to the computer (usb debugging is already enabled) it is shown in the Android Device Chooser and I can also run the application without major problems. But when I try to do the exact same thing again the device is not shown anymore. I have to unplug the usb cable and replug it. Then the device appears again. 
I guess this is not a problem with drivers as it basically works but not more times in a row...

Comment: loose cable? it happens sometimes. You may check in 'devices' tab next to 'logcat' tab. if your device appears there, I will give you a solution cuz it got disconnected from adb. If not, then loose cable it is.

Comment: There is no devices tab.

Comment: use menu>window>show View> others>search > devices. Now devices tab will appear. Check how many devices showing as 'online' there.

Comment: It shows my device while in the Android Device Chooser nothing is listed.

Comment: You said you ran the app on device earlier. Have you made any changes to code like 'minSDK' targetSDK such that your device is not compatible to your app now?

Comment: No, I didn't make any changes. And if I unplug the usb cable und replug it I can run the app once. If I want to run it again the Android Device Chooser doesn't show anything to begin with. Then I unplug and replug and it shows the device again.

Comment: And your device still is connected? ie. shows charging? If yes, then it must be a weird problem.

Comment: yes, it still is connected. That's what I thought: a weird problem.

Comment: okay... after some more research I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416532/just-upgraded-my-os-x-to-yosemite-android-device-chooser-not-showing-device-w/26425489#26425489 That's the solution. Weird problem indeed.

Comment: OMG.. this is paranormal solution!

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem after update to Yosemite. At second time device is not visible on list. Try just click ok/enter key.

Comment: Doesn't work. The OK Button is not active without any online device.