# Eclipse on Mac android bug

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I am having a strange issue ever since I installed eclipse on my mac mini (switched from windows machine). I am developing an opengl app on android and if I launch the app from eclipse, the android-opengl method OnSurfaceCreated() will be called randomly trashing the game (not supposed to happen). If I launch the game from the phone without eclipse this never happens. Also I have to unplug and replug the phone every time I want to build and launch from eclipse or else the phone doesn't appear as a choice. So I am suspecting there is something wrong with ADB. Any ideas? I have a samsung galaxy SIII. Is there a driver I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens to me too on Eclipse installed on my mac. I had to replug the device every now and then. The problem is only of the UI. If you drag a border on the device chooser UI, it will show up. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26425489/1306419 answer on [Just upgraded my OS X to Yosemite, Android Device Chooser not showing device - what to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416532/just-upgraded-my-os-x-to-yosemite-android-device-chooser-not-showing-device-w/26425489#26425489) .

Also regarding `OnSurfaceCreated()` issue, please share the error that appears in `LogCat`.