# OSX Yosemite, ADB and USB having to reconnect device all the time

Tags: android

After updating to Yosemite and all the latest ADB tools this week I'm having to reconnect my Nexus 5 each and every time I want to deploy an APK from Eclipse.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: happens to me all the time. Interested in the solution =)

Comment: With a OnePlus One and a MacBook Pro with Yosemite, the same happens to me from time to time. I have yet to find a pattern of when it fails to be found. A friend of mine has the same (occasional) problem on Windows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26425489/1791820 Could this be the solution to your problems?

Answer (score 0):

I used to get it, and it seems to be a graphical error. It doesn't happen to me any more, but when I got it I would just do the following:

When run dialog pops up:
Press down
Press enter

It SHOULD select it, even though it doesn't show up, and then it will run it on the device. The window should automatically be selected, but if it's not, just select the device window and press down then enter.