# Unable to select my Android device when running project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I'm trying to develop an Android app using the Eclipse IDE and I want to debug using my physical Moto X (2nd gen, Android version 4.4.4). I thought it was as easy as turning on USB debugging on the phone, plugging it into my macbook (OS X Yosemite 10.10.1), running my Android application from eclipse, and selecting my device.

However when the device chooser dialogue comes up, it doesn't show my moto x in there. It shows all the Android Virtual Devices I have set up, but nothing under running Android device. What's particularly mind-blowing about this to me is that I can clearly see my device in the eclipse device view as online. I can also see it by going into the sdk folder and running adb devices. The only time to doesn't show up is when I try to run the application and select what to run it on.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before? Is there something here I'm missing? I have the latest Android SDK all up to date, as well as my Eclipse (I'm running Juno if that matters). My Min SDK version is 11, and the Target is 21, so my device should be in that range. I have also tried restarting the device, eclipse, and even my macbook with no luck.

Comment: If your target is 21, your 4.4.4 device is *not* in that range.  You should be targeting SDK 19.

Comment: it is in range because Min SDK version is 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Yosemite, try to drag corner of one of the column headers in the device chooser box and it will show the device. This is a hilariously stupid bug on eclipse for Mac. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26425489/1306419).

Comment: Wow... Hours of trying to figure out what could be wrong with my device, computer, or software only to find the answer was dragging a column header.
Android studio here I come!

Answer (score 1):

There might be something wrong with eclipse. Sometimes the only solution to fix eclipse is to redownload a fresh copy of ADT from website.

You say that you can see your device when you run *adb devices*.
In this case use eclipse to build your project then use adb to install the apk on the phone:

```
adb install /path/to/projectRoot/bin/myBuild.apk
```

Better yet I would take this as a sign to forget Eclipse and move to Android Studio. Version 1.0 was [released](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) today (no more beta).

Comment: Yeah, definitely going to give Android Studio a try after this.. The solution was to drag a column header and the device magically pops up. What a joke!