# Android device disappearing from list, doesn't matter WiFi or USB debuggings

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adb, android-debug

Eclipse started to driving me crazy.

While I was debugging via USB , my device was disappearing from *Device Chooser* dialog box list after every debugging session ([same issue with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355268/eclipse-adb-frequently-disconnects-from-my-device)) I've tried to reset adb but nothing changed.

And then I decided to use debugging via WiFi. So I made all configuration as mentioned in `adb help`, successfully.  After that, in my first try it worked like a charm but after debugging session it's disappered from device chooser list again. But it's appearing in DDMS tab and `adb devices` command.

[image: It's ok in adb devices]
It's ok in adb devices

[image]
also in DDMS

But when I try to run application
[image] where is my device?!

Yes my device's Android API level is bigger than 11 and **ADB over Network** option is checked in device settings.

(I'm sure this problems are not about my USB cable or my device because I've tried them with 2 different USB cable and 2 different Android device -Galaxy S2 and XPeria Z3-. I also tried to reinstall different versions of Eclipse)

Is it time to start using Android Studio? Do you have any idea about fixing this problem? I've tried lots of things. I'm familiar with Eclipse's interface and want to keep continue using it.

Comment: it is time to go to Window -> Perspective -> DDMS on the left panel in the opened window you have a small arrow that opens a menu. select "reset adb" and try again

Comment: @ymz tried it before, nothing changed.

Comment: Honestly, it's time to start using Android Studio. I was having troubles similar to this. Then one day, Eclipse decided that my SDK didn't exist and refused to recognize it...weird stuff was going on. I got Android Studio and haven't looked back since. It isn't terribly different, but it is much easier to set up and maintain.

Comment: Honestly I have same problem in Android Studio....