# The eclips debugger can't see my tab

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Suddenly the eclipse stopped seeing the my Tablet. It was working before but don't know why this happened.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If suddenly Eclipse after a debug sessions suddenly stops seeing your device and put it offline, you could go to **DDMS -> Devices Tab** and then click the option **Reset adb**

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10355416/3919009) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

See if developer mode is enabled in the Settings menu